# What is the conditional probability $P(A|B)$ in measure theory?

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, measure-theory

In Schervish's Theory of Statistics (1995) and again in [A Measure Theoretic Formulation of Bayes' Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444080/a-measure-theoretic-formulation-of-bayes-theorem) by [@ArtemMavrin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97872/artem-mavrin),  the following equation was proved in detail

$$
\mu_{\Theta \mid X}(A \mid x) 
=  \frac{\int_A f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta) \, d\mu_\Theta(\theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta) \, d\mu_\Theta(\theta)} 
$$

but this only calculates the conditional probability $P(A|x)$. What is the equation for $\mu_{\Theta \mid X}(A \mid B) $?

Comment: Do you mean $\mu_{\Theta|B}(A|B)$ in your last line?

Comment: @jbowman,  both $\Theta$ and $X$ are random variables here, while $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets. It is explained in  ArtemMavrin post.

Comment: @jbowman I am interested in the equation for $P(A|B)$ while  ArtemMavrin post only seems to qive an equation for $P(A|X=x)$

Comment: Does $x \subseteq B$ in place of just $x$ do the job?

Comment: @jbowman, do you mean $x\in B$?

Comment: No, $x$ can be a set of points, not just a single point.  You can condition on, for example, $1 \leq x \leq 3$, not just on $x = 2.71$.  I really meant $x = B$, though, not sure why I thought of the other notation.

Comment: @jbowman, I think $x$ here means $X(\omega)=x$ where $\omega \in S$ the underlying probability space and $X$ is a measurable function (random variable). It is explained clearly in the OP's link.

Comment: @jbowman, $x\in \mathcal{X},\theta\in \Omega,B\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and $A\subseteq \Omega$.